# Angular comparing value to 'null' inside template

Tags: angularjs

I have some data returned with 'null' (string) as the value for an attribute. In the template I'm using ng-if to show 'No Info' if the value === 'null' but it's not being displayed when the value is in fact 'null'. Not sure what's going on.

```
<span ng-if="item.name !== 'null'"><span>{{item.name}}</span>
<span ng-if="item.name === 'null'" translate="{{'locales.no_info'}}"></span>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://plnkr.co/edit/4MggrwO4elAyEfM637HZ. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, in a plunkr.

Comment: @neridaj Was my answer any help or did you just miss something when you copied and pasted your code?

Comment: @TimHarker, it was a stupid mistake. I thought I left a comment before but I don't see it now. Thanks for catching the missing tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a closing tag, `</span>`.  So that is why it's not being displayed when the value is in fact 'null'!